# I can't find a bounty button

Tags: support, bounty

I want to award a bounty on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27963312/arm-mov-and-mvn-operand), but I can not longer find the link?  Did the new styling kill the bounty link or is it something to do with the number of comments?  Did the place where I award bounties change?

I can see the bounty link on other questions without the 'Run code' nor 'Show more comments'.

Comment: Or just [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065)

Comment: Ok, I clicked below (in a list of similar questions ordered by 'recent') instead of above; it is almost 48 hours.

Comment: It's only been 30 hours since the question was posted.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I knew it was more than 24hrs.  Does the rational make sense if you want to reward an existing answer?  Ie, the duplicate doesn't 'make sense' for my case.  I guess I can wait for a better answer to appear; but frankly it won't.  I will wait.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [help center about bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty):

> **How do I start a bounty? When can I start a bounty?**
>
> A bounty can be started on a question **two days** after the question was asked.

The question was asked 2015-01-15 12:19, it's not been 2 days yet.

Comment: A disabled 'bounty' with hover text might make it more obvious.  I guess that most people don't give bounties, so you won't get many duplicates and some people might think it is clutter.